# Laggy preview for image sequence in all video editing programs in Xubuntu (Kdenlive, Openshot, Sony Vegas via Wine)

Tags: xubuntu, video-editor, previews

Current os: Xubuntu 13.04

At first I thought it was Kdenlive's problem with not being able to preview image sequence in real time without being laggy, and then the same problem happens with other programs (Openshot, Pitivi) so I thought maybe all native Linux video editing programs just kind of suck, but then even Sony Vegas has the exact same problem, then I'm starting to think maybe I'm doing something wrong.

I tried to use Kdenlive to preview the image sequence with VMware in another computer and it plays smoothly. So that proves it further that I might have some problem that causes all these video editing program to not be able to preview image sequence smoothly on my computer? Previewing video clips in all these programs are totally fine.

Another small note: In both Openshot and Kdenlive, it seems like the preview does play smoothly for about 2 seconds, and then starts to lag.

I'm using nvidia current driver 304, I tried switching to nouveau just to see if it changes anything -- nope. I tried turning off compiz -- nope. I unticked "power saving over performance" and "spin down hard disk" from power management settings, still the same laggy image sequence preview.

I don't understand, my computer is not old. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem, and thought I might as well leave this question up if anyone ran into this.

The cause was both Compiz and Nvidia's proprietary current driver 304. I had antialiasing and anisotropic filtering set to "override application settings", turning it off and set it to "use application settings", untick "Enable FXAA" and "Texture sharpening" fixed the problem. I also found that using Compiz also brought back that original problem back, so I switched it off. The quality of the playback of the image sequence isn't the best, but it's bearable compare to what it was like before which was playing one frame every 30 second.